# 9patch image not working

Tags: java, android, nine-patch

I have a set of four 9patch images I wish to use for a button (ldpi to xhdpi). It appears normally on the UI designer in eclipse, but on the emulator and on my android device it stretches the image as if it were not 9patch.

Images (I can only post two links max, sorry):

ldpi
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2D6s.png

mdpi
https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7ZzG.png

hdpi (link limit reached, sorry)

xhdpi (link limit reached, sorry)

Here is the button XML:

```xml
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="@style/loginstyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="97dp"
    android:onClick="onLogin"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
```

Here is my style code:

```xml
<style name="loginstyle">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/loginbuttondr</item>
</style>
```

Here is my drawable xml (loginbuttondr.xml):

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/loginbutton"/>
</selector>
```

The image set is named loginbutton.9.png

**SOLUTION**: Thanks to @MoshEsran. The issue was that I had not added the fill guidelines (right and bottom sides) to the image.

Comment: So what does the image on your phone look like? Can you post an image?

Comment: Eclipse it appears properly: http://prntscr.com/29r5i0  and on the emulator or a real device: http://prntscr.com/29r580

Comment: Must be something wrong with your 9-patch drawables for other resolutions. Notice that you cannot simply increase the image size to make drawables for other resolution, since that the black lines will be increased proportionally, which is something you don't want because the black lines are only allowed for 1px. Can you post other drawables file if possible?

Comment: hdpi: http://i.imgur.com/RSDeUDF.png    and xhdpi: http://i.imgur.com/IH6Z46B.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem might be your patch line color is not pure black.

You must use #000000, however, currently you are having #101a05

Comment: I am still old-fashion photoshop guy

Comment: and on my screen they appear as #4C8317

Comment: @MoshErsan (might) depends on which asset you are looking at

Comment: Ah I uploaded the wrong set of 9patch images. I am currently using a proper set with #000000 for the outline and the problem is still persisting.

Comment: @Arrexel  do you use `Photoshop` or some Image Editors, to create 9Patches? or do u use 9Patch Editor?

Comment: @Arrexel I notice there are some shadow blacks on the edges of patch lines, did you remove those?

Comment: There are no shadows on the proper set of images.

Comment: @MoshErsan I use photoshop

Comment: download it, and rename it to loginbutton.9.png

Comment: there already made tool for 9Patch comes with android sdk, you can find it in `.../android-sdks/tools/draw9patch`

Comment: Thank you @MoshErsan! I guess the fill guidelines are required. It is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

A 9Patch image is intended to be stretchable. That is their function.
If the buttons do not look as you wanted, then it is likely that either;

a) Your button layout XML is incorrect for what you want to achieve (add it to your question so we can have a look).

or

b) You haven't provided 9Patch images at the correct resolution for your device.

Comment: Added the button code to the question. Also, on the real device and on the emulator it treats it as a regular image and stretches it, with the black 9patch lines still visible, like so: http://prntscr.com/29r580  In eclipse it appears properly. Example: http://prntscr.com/29r5i0

Comment: because the emulator runs on different density rather than your real device.

Comment: in the UI designer in Eclipse, you choose the device preview, maybe you have chosen a lower device, that there is a correct 9 patch image for it, lets try this experiment, delete all `loginbutton.9.png` in res folders, then just put 1 copy of it, mdpi (for example) and clean/build the project and try it on real device

Comment: Tried what you said Ersan and it had no effect. (used mdpi only)